# Ios unsupported color space error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I try to load certain textures into my opengl app I get an unsupported color space errors for seemingly compressed .png files.

If I right click and examine the textures that fail, they have the following property.

**color profile: sRGB IEC61966-2.1**

The .png appears to get this property when it's compressed. I would really like to have this feature because it reduces the texture size by ~50%.

Here is my texture loading code:

```
-(GLubyte *) generatePixelDataFromImage: (UIImage *) pic{

    GLubyte *pixelData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height *4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    CGColorSpaceRef imageCS = CGImageGetColorSpace(pic.CGImage);

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGContextRef gc = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, width, height, 8, width*4, imageCS, bitmapInfo);

    CGContextDrawImage(gc, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), pic.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(gc);
    return pixelData;
}
```

Here is the error:

> Error: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported color space. Feb 14
>   13:11:59 Garretts-iPhone myApp[712] : CGContextDrawImage:
>   invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a
>   library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby
>   contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Is there anyway to convert the texture programmatically whilst still having the benefit of reduced storage space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_color/dq_color.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH205-TPXREF128):

> Important: iOS does not support device-independent or generic color spaces. iOS applications must use device color spaces instead.

Have you tried just using `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` as the color space? Does it look ok?